# A while loop and the "this" object

Tags: javascript, loops, prototype

The code below defines a custom method for the Object's prototype that uses the native method "hasOwnProperty" to find the owner of the passed in property.

```
Object.prototype.findOwnerOfProperty = function(propName){
    var currentObject = this;
    while (currentObject !==null){
        if (currentObject.hasOwnProperty(propName)){
            return currentObject;
        }
    }
}
```

My encounters with while loops have been usually of this format:

```
while ( x < 10 ){
    // do stuff
    x++;
}
```

Say I called the "findOwnerOfProperty" method on an object:

```
newObject.findOwnerofProperty(firstProp);
```

My questions are:

1) What happens to the "this" object while the loop is running?

2) What exactly is the loop iterating through?

3) What is the difference between the first while loop and the second while loop, where the second loop has an obvious increment that explicitly changes the counter 'x' and the first loop doesnt? Which part of the first code changes the "currentObject"?

Comment: *"What happens to the "this" object while the loop is running?"* Nothing.

Comment: If the `while` loops you've encountered have usually been incrementing counters until they reach a stop point, you have not been encountering good `while` loops. That kind of loop should almost always be a `for`.

Comment: @user2357112—not necessarily. In some early implementations, while loops were a lot faster than for loops so they were sometimes preferred for a large number of iterations. Also, with live NodeLists, a reversed while loop has handy if the NodeList was being modified along the way. Of course the while test could include an assignment, but a counter is simpler and often more efficient. So there are good reasons to use a counter with a while loop. :-)

Comment: @RobG: By "reversed while loop", do you just mean a loop that counts down? Because you can do that with a for loop, so I don't see the advantage of a while for that.

Comment: Yes, and yes you can, but using a counter with a while loop isn't inherently "not good".

Comment: @RobG: There are use cases for a while with a counter, but if that's the kind you're *usually* seeing, it's an indicator that whoever's writing these loops isn't comfortable with basic language syntax. Counter-whiles should be much less common than either for loops or whiles that don't just count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property names are resolved firstly on the object itself, then on the objects on it's `[[Prototype]]` chain. You can access that chain using [*Object.getPrototypeOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.2), so you might be able to do something like:

```
Object.prototype.findOwnerOfProperty = function(propName) {
  var obj = this;
  do {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
      return obj;
    }
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  } while (obj)
}

// Some tests
var obj = {foo:'foo'};
var x = obj.findOwnerOfProperty('foo');
console.log(x == obj); // true

// Find foo on Bar.prototype
function Bar(){}
Bar.prototype.foo = 'foo';
var bar = new Bar();
var p = Object.getPrototypeOf(bar);
console.log(bar.findOwnerOfProperty('foo') == Bar.prototype); // true

// Find toString on Object.prototpye
console.log(bar.findOwnerOfProperty('toString') === Object.prototype); // true

// Non-existant property
console.log(bar.fum); // undefined
console.log(bar.findOwnerOfProperty('fum')); // undefined
```

The above returns *undefined* if no such object is found, which seems appropriate given that *null* is at the end of all `[[Prototype]]` chains and returning *null* would suggest that the property was found there.

Note that *Object.getPrototypeOf* is ES5 so not in all browsers in use.

#### Edit

It's possible that the function will be called with a value of *this* that isn't an Object, e.g.:

```
bar.findOwnerOfProperty.call(null, 'bar');
```

The desired outcome might be *undefined* or perhaps a type error, however the actual result depends on whether the code is strict or not and the value provided.

**Non–strict code**—if *this* is a primitive, then it will be set to the result of applying the abstract [*ToObject*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.9) operator to the primitive value (e.g. if it's a number, then effectively `new Number(value)`, if it's a string, then `new String(value)`).

In the case of *null* and *undefined*, *this* is set to the global object (note that applying *ToObject* to *null* or *undefined* throws an error) so the wrong inheritance chain will be checked (i.e. the global object, not *null*) and possibly the global object will be returned.

The fix for both these cases is "RTFM" (well, if there was one…) since by the time any code is executed, *this* has already been set and it's impossible to check the original call.

**Strict code**—in this case the value of *this* is not modified so a check can be made to ensure it's an Object or Function and return *undefined* otherwise:

```
Object.prototype.findOwnerOfProperty = function(propName) {
  var obj = this;

  // Only applies to strict mode
  if ((typeof obj != 'object' && typeof obj != 'function') || obj === null) return;

  while (obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
      return obj;
    }
    obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  }
}
```

So there may be different results for strict and non–strict mode, e.g.

```
bar.findOwnerOfProperty.call(7, 'toString');
```

returns *undefined* for strict code and *Number* (i.e. the Number constructor) for non–strict code (because 7 is converted to a Number object as if by `new Number(7)`, and calling *typeof* on a Number object returns `'object'`).

To achieve consistency, for values other than *null* and *undefined*, the *ToObject* operator could be emulated for strict code. Alternatively, the non–strict version could operate only on values where *typeof* returns *function* or *object*. I'll leave that decision to anyone who actually wants to implement this in anger.

Comment: I'd use a `while` or `for` loop nonetheless, just in case that someone applies your method to `null` :-)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. Really cleared it up.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between the first while loop and the second while loop

The first while loop is an infinite loop because `currentObject` never changes.

Comment: Only a *potential* infinite loop. If the test returns true, the loop ends. But if it returns false the first time… :-(